# How to use IN() to search for existence?

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am using Npgsql to connect to a Postgres database, and I want to run a query like this one:

```
 SELECT column IN('foo', 'bar') FROM table;
```

to check if the column is in a list.

I have this C# code now:

```
var list = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT column IN(:list) FROM table", myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("list", list);
```

But that doesn't work, as Npgsql makes an `ARRAY` from `list`, where it should be something else, ... but what?

Comment: `'foo', 'bar'` - is this a typo? There must be `var list = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };`

Comment: @Dennis yes that is a typo; that's what you get for mixing languages :).

Comment: Dapper may be worth looking into to make this kind of stuff simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using the `ANY` operator, as that takes an array:

```
var list = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT column = ANY(:list) FROM table", myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("list", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each item needs to be passed as an individual parameter.

These can be created dynamically, by projecting your list into parameters:

```
var list = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
var parameters = list.Select((x, i) => new NpgsqlParameter($"@item{i}", x));
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand($@"
    SELECT column IN({string.join(',', parameters.Select(x => x.ParameterName))})
    FROM table", myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
```

Comment: Concatenating literal values into your SQL means that you can't reuse the same query plans via prepared statements. Parameterizing the array with ANY as shown above is generally better.